# Conan Artifactory Jenkins Integration fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory, conan

We have a problem regarding the Jenkins Artifactory Plug-in using Conan.

Basically, we created our scripted pipeline (following the example in https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/blob/master/jenkins-examples/pipeline-examples/scripted-examples/conan-example/Jenkinsfile), which set-up the artifactory server, creates the conanClient, performs the creation of a Conan Package (by running through the conanClient the command "conan create", since our project is built via a conanfile.py recipe), uploads the package to our artifactory instance, and finally we want to clear the conan cache (through the "conan remove * -f" command).

But this last step always fails: the problem seems to be caused by the conanClient, which implicity invokes the "conan_build_info" command after the "conan remove * -f". The "conan_build_info" command fails since the "conan_build_info" apparently requires the "package" cache, which is, of course, cleared. Is this a conanClient bug (maybe because, as we read in the documentation, the conan_build_info command is not recommended to be used: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/misc/conan_build_info.html), or are we missing something?
Is there a way to perform a package creation and upload via the ConanClient, and clear the conan cache without causing the pipeline to fail?
It seems to me this is a big bogus bug, since package creation and upload via CI - Jenkins is a fondumental aspect... and of course, at the end, the conan cache must be cleared...

Here our Jenkinsfile:

```
node()
{
   // Obtain an Artifactory server instance, defined in Jenkins --> Manage:
   def server = Artifactory.server "artifactory_server"

   // Create a local build-info instance:
   def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
   buildInfo.name = "our git master pipeline"

   // Create a conan client instance:
   def conanClient = Artifactory.newConanClient()

   // Add a new repository named 'conan-local' to the conan client.
   // The 'remote.add' method returns a 'serverName' string, which is used later in the script:
   String serverName = conanClient.remote.add server: server, repo: "conan-local"
   
   // We enable strict ABI dependency propagation
   conanClient.run(command: "config set general.default_package_id_mode=package_revision_mode", buildInfo: buildInfo)
   conanClient.run(command: "config set general.revisions_enabled=1", buildInfo: buildInfo)
   conanClient.run(command: "config set general.full_transitive_package_id=1", buildInfo: buildInfo)
       
   stage('Checkout') 
   {
       // checkout from our repo...
   }

   stage('Build Release')
   {
       // Run a conan build. The 'buildInfo' instance is passed as an argument to the 'run' method:
       conanClient.run(command: "create ./project_dir channel/channel", buildInfo: buildInfo)
   }
   
   stage('Upload')
   {   
       // Create an upload command. The 'serverName' string is used as a conan 'remote', so that the artifacts are uploaded into it:
       String command = "upload our_packet/*@*/master --all -r ${serverName} --confirm"

       // Run the upload command, with the same build-info instance as an argument:
       conanClient.run(command: command, buildInfo: buildInfo)
   }

   stage("Clear Conan Cache")  
   {
       // Clean all conan cache
       String command = "remove * -f"

       // Run the remove command, with the same build-info instance as an argument:
       conanClient.run(command: command, buildInfo: buildInfo)
   }
   
   stage('Publish build info')
   {   
        // Publish the build-info to Artifactory:
       server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
   }

}
```

The error from Jenkins log:

```
[out_project] $ cmd.exe /C "conan remove "*" -f && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[out_project] $ cmd.exe /C "conan_build_info D:\jenkins\workspace\out_project@tmp\artifactory\conan.tmp8862200414119894885\conan_log.log --output D:\jenkins\workspace\out_project@tmp\artifactory\conan1112119574977543529build-info && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
[1m[31mERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\.conan\\efa5c5\\1\\conaninfo.txt'[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.RuntimeException: Conan build failed
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.Utils.launch(Utils.java:256)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.ConanExecutor.execute(ConanExecutor.java:132)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.ConanExecutor.collectConanBuildInfo(ConanExecutor.java:180)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.ConanExecutor.execCommand(ConanExecutor.java:101)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.conan.RunCommandStep$Execution.runStep(RunCommandStep.java:50)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.conan.RunCommandStep$Execution.runStep(RunCommandStep.java:37)
   at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.run(ArtifactorySynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:42)
   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: This could be a bug, I would suggest opening an issue on the project's [Github](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin). Without knowing the details, I believe a workaround could be to run the `conan remove` command directly through conan without the conanClient, since the conanClient doesn't benefit you in any way in that command (clearing a local cache that does not affect the build info)

Comment: @Prostagma Thank you for you reply. We tried with the proposed solutions, but simply invoking `conan remove` command directly doesn't work, since the conanClient used a local cache. When the pipeline run the remove command, we get: 
`D:\jenkins\workspace\our_project>conan remove * -f 
WARN: No package recipe matches '*' `. Is there a way to re-use the cache of the conanClient maybe?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jfrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin/blob/a92f8345568d3874cb9dc692ffa8505a92348431/src/main/java/org/jfrog/hudson/pipeline/common/Utils.java#L499) is how the ConanHome is chosen. So either set `CONAN_USER_HOME` env var, or provide conanClient a [userHome](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Scripted+Pipeline+Syntax#ScriptedPipelineSyntax-ConanBuildswithArtifactory) and delete cache from there.

Comment: Thanks again, but this does not work either. We provided conanClient a userHome: `Artifactory.newConanClient userHome: "${WORKSPACE}/conan_home".toString()`, and invoked the command `conan remove * -f` from there... not a single cache dir was deleted, and the output was the same: No package found, even when we checked through `conan search *`. Something strange is happening...

Comment: You should probably run `CONAN_USER_HOME="${WORKSPACE}/conan_home" conan remove * -f`. Note that the conanClient uses a temporary home if a user home is not provided, so the cache does not interfere with the machine's conan home nor with between different builds. So I guess if the you'd like to clear the cache only for storage reasons, you can just periodically delete all the conan.tmp* dirs from the jenkins workspace altogether